# Integrating a wave maker module into spring 3 application

Tags: java, module, spring-3, spring-integration, wavemaker

I have a module developed in wave maker- 6.5.1. Now I want to integrate the same in Spring 3 web application.
Can anyone guide with how is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

WaveMaker applications are just Spring 3 web applications. WaveMaker is a drag and drop builder for building a web gui (using dojo javascript toolkit) on top of a Java application (using Spring 3).

You can find out more on how to work with the Spring framework and wavemaker here:

http://dev.wavemaker.com/wiki/bin/Spring

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate wavemaker (with a lot of effort) into a spring3 project, maybe you have to copy and setup too many options manually. Either, you can have 2 differents proyects that can share the same DB, if you want to do some sort of communication  between the projects, you can implements some webservices (in both side if it necesary) and you can send data or do some tricks in the apps.